# How to persist Properties in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

In my jenkins pipeline I am working with properties stored in file.

I can read properties from file and add new items to the map using this code, but I do not understand how to persist my changes.

```
node('hozuki-best-girl') {
    def propertiesPath = "${env.hozuki_properties}"
    def props = readProperties file: propertiesPath
    props['versionCode'] = 100500
}
```

What should I do in order to persist my changes? There is no writeProperties method here https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readproperties-code-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text

Comment: Please share the solution, if you got it.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use yaml format instead of properties.

it also simple and human readable and in jenkins-pipeline there are read and write operations for yaml

or you can use this kind of code:

```
@NonCPS
def propsToString(Map map){
    return new StringWriter().with{w-> (map as Properties).store(w, null); w; }.toString()
}

writeFile file: propertiesPath, text: propsToString(props)
```

Comment: writeYaml can only write a new file it cannot overwrite the existing file, therefore no point to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Phoenix AutoTest Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/phoenix-autotest/) has a `writeProperties` step.