# How to update config properties file from a Jenkin Pipeline groovy script?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline, maven-2, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkin Pipeline. We have maven based selenium-java Automation framework.  I am creating a Jenkin Pipeline groovy script to invoke the Automation framework.

In the framework we have config.properties file in which Application url , username and password is stored.

config.properties:

Url=https://#########/login.jsp

Username=########

Password=########

Requirement: We need to take the Application URL , Username and Password as a Jenkin parameter , and run the automation suite accordingly.

Question: From Pipeline groovy script  how can I update the config.properties file at runtime? Is there any possibility of creating a java class inside the framework to update config file and invoke the java class from groovy script.

I've tried the following code

```
node{ 
  stage("props file"){ 
    script { 
      def props = """Url=https://#########/login.jsp Username=######## 
                     Password=########""" 
      writeFile interpolate: true ,file: 'ui-automation/fw/config/config.properties', text: props 
      def str = readFile file: 'ui-automation-fw/config/config.properties' 
      echo str
    } 
   }
 }
```

Appreciate any help on how to fix the code to achieve the needed result

Comment: please share your work around.

Comment: Hello. Work around is take the parameters in maven command and except the variables in pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Use [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) step to write the file.

The following example writes and reads the file `config.properties`

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages{
     stage("props file"){
        steps{
            script {

                def props = """Url=https://#########/login.jsp
Username=########
Password=########"""
                writeFile file: "config.properties", text: props
                def str =  readFile file: "config.properties"
                echo str

            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Update:**
If the properties file already exists you can use the [readProperties](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) step to load the properties.

Comment: Hello Yuri. Thanks for replying. Config.properties file is inside my framework . Jenkin build first pull the source code from git in workspace. Do I need to provide complete path of the property file in my script?

Comment: @sudhirranjanSwain I've added a link to readProperties step. Please read the documentation and try to implement your solution. If you will have any issue please edit your question with more details

Comment: Hello Yuri. Great . Thanks a lot.  This works. Just one issue. This solution overwrites the whole file . What If I want to update only these three values without touching the others values in config.properties.

Comment: node{
 
  stage("props file"){
        
            script {
def props = """Url=https://#########/login.jsp
Username=########
Password=########"""

                
                writeFile interpolate: true ,file: 'ui-automation-fw/config/config.properties', text: props
                def str =  readFile file: 'ui-automation-fw/config/config.properties'
                echo str

            }
         }
      
} -- This is  overwriting all content and adding above three lines . But I want only the values of these keys should be updated. As my config file contains other keys

Comment: @sudhirranjanSwain Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51739266/7571258

Comment: @YuriG. , thanks for this, can you help with writing back the properties when  it's read by readProperties ? since readProperties returns an object/map instead of text

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update one property in a properties-file, I think it is easiest to:

- Read the file as proprties.
- Change the property.
- Serialize to String.
- Write that string to properties-file again.

Here is an example updating `version` in `gradle.properties`:

```
HashMap<String,String> props = readProperties(file: "gradle.properties")
props.version = newVersion

def propsString = props.
    collect { k, v -> "$k=$v"}
    .join("\n")

writeFile file: "gradle.properties", text: propsString
```